# How to explicitly specify the 'inverse' @OneToMany relationship in JPA

Tags: java, generics, jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA discriminators to obtain specific sub classes as follows (class names changed for simplicity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TYPE")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="SUB_TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class Type {
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="TID")
   private Foo foo; 
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Type1 extends Type {
    //Type1 stuff
}

//Other Type subclasses
```

As you can see "Type" class is in a many-to-one relationship with the Foo class, however in generics as `Set<Type1>` is not a subtype of `Set<Type>` we cannot just speicify the 'inverse' relationship in Foo as   `Set<Type> types;`

Therefore my Foo class uses wildcards but also ensures that only subclasses of Type can be set as types as follows;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo {

    //bi-directional one-to-many association to Type
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo")
    Set<?> types;

    public Set<?> getTypes() {
            return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(Set<? extends Type> types) {
            this.types = types;
    }   
}
```

The question is - how do I explicitly tell JPA that the Set should be of type 'Type'? If this is not possible, what are my alternatives to setting this inverse relationship, while still using discriminators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OneToMany annotation can specify the targetEntity:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", targetEntity = Type.class)
  Set<?> types;
```

This is optional when generics can be used to define the type, but required in your situation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html